# how do I get latest satellite maps from Google map api V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Today I was trying add a google map(satellite view) to my project when i located my place in google map site its looks like below

Captured from maps.google.com:

[image]

When I load same location in my web site this looking like below

captured from my project :
[image]

am using below code to do this stuff am missing anything ...

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-tool'), {
  zoom:6,
  center: {lat: -37.729737, lng: 144.814376}, 
  mapTypeControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  fullscreenControl: true,
  zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
     position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
  },
  scrollwheel: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID

});
```

My question is how do I get a clear satellite map view like what we get in maps.google.com in JavaScript API?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Both Google Maps and the posted code show me the same tiles.  You might have caught Google in the middle of a tile update.

Comment: @scotthenninger question updated

Comment: @geocodezip sorry I didn't got u there...

Comment: Your code does not reflect the same location than your images show... But I also don't get the same tiles than on maps.google.com.

Comment: oh okay please change the co-ordinates to this -37.729737, 144.814376

Comment: updated the question too

Comment: The thing is there seem to be no rule about that. Google doesn't say anywhere that the imagery is the same in the API than on maps.google.com.

Comment: @MrUpsidown hmm ya I understand that... now currently am using free version of Map V3 api. If I upgrade it to premium version do you think it load updated satellite map image...?? I checked in there pricing plans they not mentioned about updated satellite view so do you have any idea about it...

Comment: I don't know. You might want to contact their sales or support team. But if they don't mention that anywhere I would assume that they don't provide "upgraded" imagery.

Comment: @MrUpsidown hmm thanks man...

Answer (score 3):

Only Google Maps for Work API will give you the access to the latest and higher resolution images. The images shown on the maps.google.com are extruded with elevation data on it and displayed in WebGL canvas, it is expected to look differently than what you see when simply use the out-of-box satellite view from the API.